# I cant eliminate matrix, where is mistake?

Tags: c, matrix

I have a matrix 3x3 = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
    and I need eliminate this matrix to 2x2: {{5,6},{8,9}} (simply by cutting).
    So I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int matrix2[1][1],m,n;
    int matrix[2][2]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    for(m=0;m<2;m++){
      for(n=0;n<2;n++){
        matrix2[m][n]=matrix[m+1][n+1];
        printf("element on %i m and %i n is %i\n",m,n,matrix2[m][n]);
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but I can't get the right result. Do you have an idea?

Comment: your arrays are too small.

Comment: Your compiler should be yelling at you. Please listen to it.

Comment: Excuse me but are you actually getting "wrong result" or maybe you just cannot compile your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although arrays are indexed starting at zero, you declare them using the number of elements in the array. Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int matrix2[2][2],m,n;
    int matrix[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    for(m=0;m<2;m++){
      for(n=0;n<2;n++){
        matrix2[m][n]=matrix[m+1][n+1];
        printf("element on %i m and %i n is %i\n",m,n,matrix2[m][n]);
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```